# Run docker and keep zshhistory from host (zsh shell) in docker container (bash shell)

Tags: bash, docker, zsh, dockerfile

I am using options:

```
HIST_FILE=/root/.bash_history -v ~/.zshhistory:/root/.bash_history
```

but it is not getting the zshhistory in the container.

Comment: This is probably my ignorance of docker showing, but what is `-v` doing here? Strictly from a shell perspective, this looks like an attempt to run a command named `-v` with `~/.../.bash_history` as an argument, in an environment where `HIST_FILE` is set to `/root/.bash_history`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to use volume with `-v` option and trying to set environment variable with `HIST_FILE=/root/.bash_history` for container. 
In this case correct syntax is to set an environment variable with `-e` option, e.g. `-e HIST_FILE='/root/.bash_history'` and mount required volume with `-v` option, e.g. `-v ~/.zshhistory:/root/.bash_history`.
Complete command will be like `docker run -e HIST_FILE='/root/.bash_history' -v ~/.zshhistory:/root/.bash_history <image_name>`